# Does Leaflet layer 'add' event not fire properly?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

A popup won't open until the data file has loaded and the layer is added to the map - that's pretty obvious. I figured it would help to bind it to the 'add' event - but that never fires:

```
var l1 = omnivore.kml('data/Niveauregulering01a.kml');
var pop = '<img src="content/img/whatever.jpg" alt="..." style="width:300px;"/>'
l1.on('add', function(){
  console.log('add');
  l1.openPopup();
});
l1.bindPopup(pop).addTo(map);
```

There seems to be no other event that I can bind it to:
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-add

Any suggestions?

Comment: NB: I used to develop with OpenLayers 2.x for years - now just getting to know Leaflet. The documentation confuses me - I'd expect a super class for all layer types that they would inherit from. The class structure in Leaflet seems less structured to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
map.on('layeradd', function(layer, layername){

});
```

You should bind the event to the map object.

/**UPDATE****/

You cannot bind the popup directly to `omnivore.kml`, according to [their docs](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) the returned object is a `L.geoJson()` layer -- so a pool of features.

Try to bind the popup on each feature:

```
var KML_layer = L.geoJson(null, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.description);
    }
}).addTo(map);

var runLayer = omnivore.kml('line.kml', null, KML_layer);

//and so on
```

Comment: Strange, it fires twice, but it doesn't open the popup: `var l1 = omnivore.kml('data/file.kml?'); var pop = '<img src="file.jpg"/>'; l1.bindPopup(pop); m.on('layeradd', function(e){ vg.log(e); l1.openPopup() }); l1.addTo(m);`

Comment: I have an issue with map 'load' event: `m.on('load', function(){  var $ib = $('#vgInfoButtonsContainer'), $lc = $('.leaflet-control-layers:first');  console.log($ib,$lc);  $ib.append( $lc.detach() );  });` - the event never fires. If I use e.g. 'focus' or 'click' events, they fire as expected.

Comment: but this is out of the question scope, is your initial question solved?

Comment: Thanks, it sort of works. I bind KML_layer.openPopup() and a console.log to the map's 'layeradd' event and the popup opens allright. The event fires hundreds or even thousands of times. That is very disturbing!

Comment: Pusling: My workaround before was `setTimeout(function(){l1.openPopup()}, 500)` which worked fine - i.e. it was not a problem to bind and open a popup on what omnivore returned - only when bound to the 'addlayer' event it was not possible. Combined with the 'load' event never firing - seems to me that events are unreliable in Leaflet?